# Why does the callback not have method variables in scope?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the below code, I want to be able to use the value that the user typed in when the button is clicked but `newTaskTitle` comes up as `null` inside the `onPressed` callback. `newTaskTitle` seems to be in scope in `onChanged` but not in `onPressed`. What am I missing here?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoey/constants.dart';

class AddTaskSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        // constraints: BoxConstraints.,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: kAccentColour,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (value) {
                newTaskTitle = value;
                print(newTaskTitle);
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(kAccentColour),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print(newTaskTitle);
                // Navigator.pop(context, newTaskTitle);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the widget extends `StatelessWidget` the assignment of `newTaskTitle` wont work as you expect.

You can extend `StatefulWidget` and assign the variable inside a call to `setState()` to get the value to work as you expect.

Comment: I understand that `StatefulWidget` will solve the problem. Is there any possibility to get the same behaviour using `StatelessWidget`?

Comment: Not really. 

Although a State Management solution like flutter_redux will allow you to use a Stateless Widget to display the data and emit an action but its will just move location of the state from the Widget to a Store.

In flutter its helpful to think using the "Flux Architecture" that is Data Down, Actions Up.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a stateless widget,you should use StatefulWidget